# How to play an audio file continuously in java?

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I am making a small program that needs to play a file continuously. Following is the code which I wrote to play the file once, but I am not aware how to do it continuously. Somebody help please.

```
public class TanpuraAudio {

    AudioStream as = null;
    String fileName = "C://s.wav";
    InputStream in = null;

    public void play() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Media file not present in C drive.");
        }

        try {
            as = new AudioStream(in);

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        AudioPlayer.player.start(as);

    }

    public void stop() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        AudioPlayer.player.stop(as);
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd have to implement something that re-starts the audio track once the track is over. Probably you'll want to do this on a separate thread as to not mess with the rest of the application. Welcome to concurrency, now you have more problems to deal with. ;-P

Answer (score 4):

You may be looking for `Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY`, illustrated in [*Playing a Clip*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info).

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on a Tanpura, also! I have a prototype that uses FM synthesis to generate the drone tones. Am working on the interface and to allow tuning of the individual notes.

I would not recommend AudioPlayer as the mean of playing the sound file. Instead I'd use Clip or SourceDataLine.

Clip can be looped, as correctly stated by trashgod. However, it might be tricky dealing with the point at which the loop restarts.

To play a wav file, I'd consider using a SourceDataLine for output. To handle the looping, I would make two SourceDataLines, and alternate them. You can also overlap the ends to make a smooth transition between the beginning and the end of the file. It is possible to use Thread.sleep() method to provide the timing of the loops if there is some "give" possible in the overlap, as Thread.sleep() can be off by as much as 15msec on a Windows OS.

For myself, I generate the tones with a Java polyphonic synthesizer of my own creation, overlapping the notes. I'm not sure I'm ready to explain all the details of FM synthesis however. It is a big topic. Also, I'm using a "mixer" that I wrote, somewhat on the scale of the mixer in the Java Library "TinySound" (available on github if you don't wish to make your own audio mixer).

TinySound could be of help in terms of simplifying the handling the two copies of the SourceDataLine or even two Clips (if you decided to overlap the ends of the Clips rather than using the built-in continuous loop function.